# How to raise customizable ValueError for input containing two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input, valueerror

I am trying to understand raising an exception little better.Below is `python` code, as you can see I am asking for two date inputs from user. If user types "2022" and hit enter it is returning `python` `ValueError` with msg `"Not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"`. Instead what I would like to do is if user types year,month or date then instead of python default ValueError. It should raise an Error saying "Incorrect date entered, please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format ONLY" and should display the input box again for user to enter correct date. My question is how to raise customizable ValueError and ask the user to renter the dates?

Any help will be appreciated!

**Code**

```
def validate(date_text):
        try:
            for y in date_text:
                if not datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d'):
                    raise ValueError
                else:
                    return True
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect date format, please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format ONLY")
            return False
while True:
    start_date,end_date= input("Enter employee start and termination date separated by (,)  in YYYY-MM-DD format only: ").split(",")
    if validate(start_date) and validate(end_date):
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue using below code. Basically, I needed another try & except block in while statement. Thanks @Иван Балван for feedback!

```
def validate(date_text):
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect date format, please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format ONLY")
            return False

while True:
    try:
        start_date,end_date= input("Enter employee start and termination date separated by (,)  in YYYY-MM-DD format only: ").split(",")
        if validate(start_date) and validate(end_date):
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect date enetered, please enter both dates in YYYY-MM-DD format ONLY")
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` because your are setting 2 variables to `input('...').split(',')`. They expect a string consisting of 2 parts, divided by a comma. For example if you input a string with more than one comma, you will get `too many values to unpack`.

Its got to be like this:

```
Enter two values divided by a comma:1,2
```

Then, i find that your first `raise ValueError` statement is not necessary. If the argument to `datetime.datetime.strptime` is incorrect it won't go to that `raise` anyway.

I would dispose of it, along with the `if` block:

```
import datetime
def validate(date_text):
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect date format, please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format ONLY")
            return False
while True:
    start_date,end_date= input("Enter employee start and termination date separated by (,)  in YYYY-MM-DD format only: ").split(",")
    if validate(start_date) and validate(end_date):
        break
```

Comment: Correct. I am taking 2 inputs from user separated by comma. If I add "2022," in your above suggested code then I am receiving the error that I want. But If I type "2022" alone without comma. I am still getting Python's ValueError INSTEAD of my Error i.e "Incorrect date format". How do I fix that ? I would like to receive inputs separated by comma only so if user types "2022" without comma then it should raise "Incorrect date format" error instead of Python's default ValueError